# Using EasyMock with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, testng, easymock

This seems easy but i don't know how to do it. We have a state machine where events get sent via an EventManager class when a transition is triggered. This is started in a new thread because we don't want to block the current thread while distributing events.

Let's say I forgot to expect a method call while mocking. The test should fail now. But it doesn't because the thread catches the exception. I also don't want to propagate the expection because the state machine stops when it gets an exception.

```
public class TestStackoverflow {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        EventManager eventManager = EasyMock.createStrictMock(EventManager.class);
        EasyMock.replay(eventManager);
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.executeStuff(eventManager);
        EasyMock.verify(eventManager);
    }

    private class MyClass{
        public void executeStuff(final EventManager eventManager){
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    eventManager.sendEvent();
                }  
            }.start();
        }
    }

    interface EventManager{
        public void sendEvent();
    }
}
```

eventManager.sendEvent() throws java.lang.AssertionError, but the unit test doesn't fail.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.AssertionError:
  Unexpected method call EventManager.sendEvent():
        at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
        at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
        at at.ac.TestStackoverflow$EventManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cbb0f0e1.sendEvent(<generated>)
        at at.ac.TestStackoverflow$MyClass$1.run(TestStackoverflow.java:27)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.58 sec
```

How can i test this situation?

Comment: The thread doesn't catch the exception. if sendEvent() throws one, the thread "breaks" like your mainthread would, if an unhandled exception would be thrown in it. declare your sendEvent() throwing an exception. public void sendEvent() throws Exception; this will force you to try-catch it in the run() of the thread and there you have to handle it. if the test shall fail then force it to fail in the catch. Did i help you? I am not sure if i understood your problem

Comment: Yes, but this would only work for the example. In reality the class which is tested is not inside the unit test, and I won't use Assert.fail() outside of the unit test.

Comment: well i dont know that much about unit tests, i am new to it. but as far as i know you have two ways. a) force it to fail by using Assert.fail() b) change a flag like a boolean or something and test it after you ran through your code. example boolean failed = false. at the end of your code do if(failed)*force it to fail/produce an error/whatever to make it fail*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the exception did get propagated back to your test, it still might not work as it looks like there might be a race condition.

For example, in your test, "executeStuff" would start the thread, but it might not actually get a chance to run straight away.

If the main thread continues, it might get to the "verify" statement before the other thread had a chance to run.

If you change things slightly so that the Thread is created outside your class, it will be easier to test.

You can then use an UncaughtExceptionHandler to get round your original problem, for example...

```
public class TestStackoverflow {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        TestExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new TestExceptionHandler();
        EventManager eventManager = EasyMock.createStrictMock(EventManager.class);
        EasyMock.replay(eventManager);

        // Create a MyClass - pass in the eventManager
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(eventManager);

        // Create thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(myClass);
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);

        // Run your code
        thread.start();

        // WAIT FOR THREAD TO FINISH
        thread.join();

        // Check no exceptions were thrown
        exceptionHandler.verifyNoExceptions();
    }

    private class TestExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        private Throwable e;

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            this.e = e;
        }

        public void verifyNoExceptions() {
            if(e != null) {
                throw new AssertionError("BOOM! Exception caught", e);
            }
        }

    }

    private class MyClass implements Runnable {
        private EventManager eventManager;

        public MyClass(EventManager eventManager) {
            this.eventManager = eventManager;
        }

        public void run(){
            eventManager.sendEvent();
        }
    }

    interface EventManager{
        public void sendEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Thread.start in another location in your code, check out the Executors stuff in the java.concurrent.executors package - it makes mocking things like that easier

Comment: Your solution would only work if i can add the UncaughtExceptionHandler from the unit test. Unfortunately the thread is created very deep in the tested class and I would have to change multiple classes just to pass the ExceptionHandler to the threads.

Comment: @MarkSitro look into using this method instead... Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler ex)

Answer (score 0):

what `createStrictMock` does is it creates a rigid mock of your Class,which will throw exception if methods called in code are not expected in that particular order in Testclass. This leads to  `Unexpected method call` exception(the exception shouldn't occur in first place for successful completion of test case).

you need to create a nice mock i.e. `Easymock.createNiceMock(EventManager.class);`

this exception should be solved

Good luck!

Comment: That solves the exception but the test still doesn't fail like it should. Is there any way to tell EasyMock to throw no exception but still register the attempted method call to fail the test?

Comment: but if an exception,is not thrown now, what do you want to catch?
put a try-catch and it should suffice